# Typeahead js Not Working, same structure copied from another working one

Tags: typeahead.js

Ok, I know this may be a little basic question, but I am tired, I have another 4 typeaheads working very well in the same way, almost identhic structures, but this one is dead.

```
    <div id="divconcpingresos">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" 
     id="addon_cp_ingreso">Concepto</span>
    </div>
    <input id="cp_ingreso" class="typeahead form-control" 
     type="text" placeholder="Seleccione un concepto" />
    </div>
```

The JS file is just a copy from another three working typeaheads, of course I replaced every variable very carefully (about 4 hours) and I can't find the error here or in HTML file,

```
    var baseconceptosingresos = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: 
    Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Description'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    identify: function (obj) { return 
    obj.idconcepto_ingresos; },
    remote: {
        url: '/api/BuscaConceptoIngreso?id=QUERY',
        wildcard: 'QUERY'
    }
});

$('#divconcpingresos .typeahead')
    .typeahead({
        hint: false,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 5,
        classNames: {
            input: 'form-control',
        }
    },
        {
            name: 'listaconceptosingresos',
            limit: 10,
            source: baseconceptosingresos,
            display: 'Description'
        }
    )
    .bind("typeahead:selected", function (ev, conceptoseleccionado) {
        vmcingreso = conceptoseleccionado.idconcepto_ingresos;
        cpi_ok = 1;
        console.log(vmcingreso);

    })
    .bind("typeahead:change", function (e, concepto) {
        if (cpi_ok == 1) {
            cpi_ok = 0;
        }
        else {
            $("#divconcpingresos .typeahead").typeahead('val', '');
        }
    });
```

My API is working well, this is a test using POSTMAN

GET https://localhost:44314/api/BuscaConceptoIngreso?id=marino

```
    [
     {
      "idconcepto_ingresos": 1,
      "idUnidadSAT": 1,
      "CodeProdServ": "78101903",
      "IdentificationNumber": "0",
      "Description": "Transporte marino a carretera (por 
       camión) (Transporte con salida marítima y destino a 
       carretera (por camión))",
      "Price": 600.000000,
      "CuentaPredial": "0",
      "visible": true
     }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the problem, today Chrome decided to read an old version of my js file, so never tried to execute the typeahead command.

My advice: always clean internet cache when developing.